# How does rendering a comment alongside the PHP opening tag lead to an "unexpected T_STRING"?

Tags: php, grammar

The following code:

```
<?php//comment
error_reporting(0);
```

[results](http://ideone.com/cEY9F) (at least in 5.2.11) in:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

... which I find quite bizarre.

Whether or not `<?php//comment` should be allowed verbatim, I propose that there can be no doubt as to the bugginess of the *contents* of the parse error.

That's because there is no `T_STRING` in sight (though I do understand that productions may form other productions to imbue precedence, e.g. `additive-expression`s encapsulating multiplication operations, and the like).

Can anyone with an understanding of the PHP grammar explain how this has come about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the following snippet which looks for the `<?php` opening tag. Note the requirement of a trailing space, horizontal tab or new line.

```
<INITIAL>"<?php"([ \t]|{NEWLINE}) {
    <snip>
    return T_OPEN_TAG;
}
```

<sup>(Source: [zend_language_scanner.l from PHP 5.3.10](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_10/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?view=markup#l1564))</sup>

This means that PHP doesn't see your code as a normal (long) open tag, but rather as having a short open tag.

```
<INITIAL>"<?" {
    if (CG(short_tags)) {
        <snip>
        return T_OPEN_TAG;
    } else {
        goto inline_char_handler;
    }
}
```

<sup>(Source: [zend_language_scanner.l from PHP 5.3.10](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_10/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l?view=markup#l1574)</sup>

The short tag does not require the trailing whitespace.

So, the different parts of your code that PHP sees are `<?`, `php`, `//comment`, `error_reporting`…. The `php` is taken to be a constant (which doesn't exist, see below). Then there is a comment, which is fine. However the next step is to call the `error_reporting()` function.  This is not something that is allowed to happen at this point and it is now that PHP bails out, complaining that the identifier (the `T_STRING`) `error_reporting` was not expected.

To demonstrate this, lets try some code that does work (meaning: PHP code is executed successfully) with `short_open_tag` enabled, but won't with `short_open_tag` disabled.

```
<?php//comment
;
```

With `error_reporting` high enough to show notices, you'll be able to see what goes wrong as the output is something like:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in example.php on line 2

With `short_open_tag` turned off, the output will be the code in plain text since PHP does not try to execute it.

Finally, a little reminder of the description about `T_STRING` in the [List of Parser Tokens](http://php.net/tokens) which says that `T_STRING` is for (don't ask me why it's not `T_IDENTIFIER`, `T_BAREWORD` or something less confusing):

> identifiers, e.g. strings, object oriented keywords like parent and self, functions, classes and more are matched.

Comment: As I indicate in my question, I don't really care about `<?php//comment` being invalid. I'm asking: why does the error mention a string that doesn't exist?

Comment: It doesn't mention anything about a *string* that doesn't exist. It says, unexpected T_STRING which (as explained in other comments/answers) is something entirely different to the string type in PHP. And that question has already been answered.

Comment: So it would seem. _That_ is the answer then

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see my update, hopefully it provides a sort of explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple. `token_get_all()` returns parsed version of code. It returns following code (when using `var_dump()` on result).

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(367)
    [1]=>
    string(2) "<?"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(307)
    [1]=>
    string(3) "php"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(365)
    [1]=>
    string(10) "//comment
"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(307)
    [1]=>
    string(15) "error_reporting"
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [4]=>
  string(1) "("
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(305)
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [6]=>
  string(1) ")"
  [7]=>
  string(1) ";"
}
```

The problem is obvious when you look at it. It sees `<?` (`T_OPEN_TAG`) and `php` (`T_STRING`). If you will parse `<?php // ok` you will get following result.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(367)
    [1]=>
    string(6) "<?php "
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(365)
    [1]=>
    string(5) "// ok"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Can you notice that `T_OPEN_TAG` is `<?php[SPACE]`. Also, PHP reserves versions of start tag with `\t`, `\r` and `\n` following it. My reasoning would be avoiding breaking BC. In old versions of PHP, PHP didn't had `<?php` and you could easily do `<?phpinfo();?>` snippet to get information about version of PHP. If PHP team would change the grammar, it would cause to activate `info();` function, even if it previously worked. Or... they wanted to avoid confusing letters after `php`. Seeing `<?phprequire` would be somewhat strange, so it's better to avoid anything like this. But, it's just my guess, as this is only thing which could break.

Also, just small information I forgot to add. Functions (unless those are variable functions or something) are `T_STRING`. They're recognized by having `(` sign after `T_STRING`. It's not really that strange (but the fact that they've named something that obviously isn't string `T_STRING` is pretty strange... for me... `T_BAREWORD` or something like this would be better... ).

Comment: I wouldn't have expected `php` to be a `T_STRING`, but perhaps that's just my poor memory...? Surely it's a `T_UNENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`?

Comment: I've got a feeling this only errors out if short_open_tags is enabled. Does this mean that with it disable it is tokenised as `<?php` being the `T_OPEN_TAG`? (Or did I just imagine that)

Comment: And if `php` is being lexed distinctly from the open tag, then why doesn't [this](http://ideone.com/CjGqX) `<? whatever//lol ?>` yield a similar issue? Why is `whatever` magically valid there?

Comment: @Cags: Either PHP would parse `<?php` and then backtrack into failure, or we just wouldn't enter PHP mode, I guess

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `whatever` is constant. `//` comments continue until end of line **or** until they hit `T_CLOSE_TAG` (mentioned in documentation). When `?>` is met, semicolon is automatically inserted, even if it doesn't exist (it's mentioned in documentation). For more fun, run `<?php $val->?>`.

Comment: @Cags: The text is just echoed when `short_open_tags` is turned off as it doesn't see `<?php\s`.

Comment: @GlitchMr: `whatever` doesn't exist. Conversely, is `php` not also a constant in the original example?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, if constant doesn't exist, as far I know PHP just makes string with name of constant and makes `E_NOTICE`. Weird behavior, but still...

Comment: @GlitchMr: Lexical parsers should not be imbuing semantics on tokens.

Comment: @GlitchMr: OK, you've answered my question by demonstrating what `T_STRING` really is (and I've [confirmed](http://codepad.org/6q6sU4iW) it). Can you promote this point more strongly in your answer? Your final paragraph is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between the <?php and //comment ... This should rectify the issue.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked for an _explanation_ of the parse error, which mentions `T_STRING` where clearly no strings are present.

Answer (score 0):

The `<?php` opening tag MUST be followed by whitespace.

In my test (PHP 5.3.8) the `<?php//` was not treated as an opening tag, and the source was printed instead.

Comment: Because that's how it's defined? That's like asking "why is the opening tag `<?php` in the first place?".

Comment: No, it's not. I'm asking why the parser suddenly thinks there's a string in that code. As I indicated in my question, I want the contents of the error explained, not the fact that I get one.